# Some Outlook search results disappear after opening

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook 2010 on Windows 7 Pro SP1 64 bit (in domain).
Connected as "Online with Microsoft Exchange".

If I do a search (ctrl-e) in Inbox and get for example 10 hits, if I open and close the found messages, some of them disappear from the result list.

They disappear right after I open them.

This seems completely random. Some messages in the same search disappear this way, some not. If I clear the search and search again using the same search term, the result is different (same results, but the same messages as before do not disappear after opening).

It is very annoying, as sometimes I open search results, close them and then want to open them again.

Due to the "random" nature I suspect a bug and not some "hidden" setting.
In any case, suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2636883

Microsoft's solution is to install the following update rollup:
[2661854](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2661854) Description of Update Rollup 2 for Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 2

You use Microsoft Office Outlook in online mode in a Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 environment.
You set the Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane option in Outlook.

"Note To set this option, follow these steps:
In Outlook, click File, select Options, and then select Mail.
In the Outlook panes field, click Reading Pane.
In the Reading Pane window, click to select the Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane check box.
You search for a keyword, and some message items are returned.
In this scenario, the returned message items can disappear from the search results view after a while. This occurs when messages are marked as unread in the view."

"The issue occurs because Exchange Server 2010 removes the returned message items of which the read/unread attribute has changed from the search result view when it updates the view. However, it does not add the message items back to the search result view after the update is complete."

Comment: Stating it's a known problem isn't really a solution.  Your link includes a solution.  However, if the link breaks, your answer would provide no benefit.  This answer would be much more useful if you include the solution here and use the link for reference.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have the "Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane" option enabled and the messages are already all read.

Comment: The server is on SP3 already, so this is not it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Disabling Server Assisted Search

Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Troubleshooting-Outlook-search-issues-2556b11f-f4d8-46be-b0a7-de33a3f4f066#bkmk_sharedmailbox

Fix:

In Windows, right-click Start, and then select Run. In the Open: box type regedit, and then click OK. This will open the registry editor.

In the registry editor dialog box, find this subkey in the registry, and then click it:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Search
```

Click Edit > New > DWORD Value.

Type DisableServerAssistedSearch for the name of the DWORD, and then press Enter.

Right-click DisableServerAssistedSearch, and then click Modify.

In the Value data box, type 1 to enable the registry entry, and then click OK.

Close the registry editor, and then restart Windows.

Comment: I tried this. Had to add 'Search' as a key. Unfortunatly it did not work